# Selecting multiple values in multiple drop down lists

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select multiple values in excel from two different drop down lists. I have code that can select multiple values on one drop down and would like to be able to do the same for another drop down list with different values. Can I use the code below and modify it or is there another easier way to do this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 45 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
```

`exitHandler:
      Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`

Comment: Hi @pnuts. The other question hasn't been answered either. But it is similar as I need to be able to select values in a drop down and place them in the same cell. The code shown can only do it for one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 45 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If    
exitHandler: Application.EnableEvents = True End Sub
```

I used a conditional `Or` to make it possible to select multiple values from two different drop down lists. This is shown in the code `If Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 45 Then`